# Image array won't draw to canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, setinterval

I'm learning JavaScript. It would be great if someone could explain where did I do a mistake.

I have an array with picture links and put them into the function, which should draw an image in canvas for every picture with link.

```
function draw(imgs){

    var step = 0;  // I want to start with zero;

    imgs.forEach(function(src){   // then go through the array links

    // and I want to draw the images from the array

    con.drawImage(src, 0, step, 200 , 150)

        step += 20;  // This is the step for the next picture

    console.log(step)
    console.log(src)
    })

    console.log(imgs);
}
```

Then execute:

```
window.onload = function(){
    setInterval(function(){
      loadImg(arr, draw)    
    }, 1000)
...
```

And it's shows me the first picture of my array and after `setInterval` the last picture.

Sorry for bad description, it's  5am

P.S.

loadImage is the function that create an array with few src of images:

```
function loadImg(linkArr, draw){
    var imgs = [];

        linkArr.forEach(function(link){
            var img = new Image();

            img.src = link
            imgs.push(img);


        })
            draw(imgs)

    };
```

Comment: What is this loadImg() you're calling ?

Comment: You forgot to show us the `draw` function that probably canns than the `draw( img )` function. Also: can you please explain **why you use a setInterval** for every 1000ms to do what? draw the same images over and over on canvas? isn't that odd? Or probably take a good sleep and explain tomorrow what you're actually up to.

Comment: Sorry, I've add the description of that function, it's just create an array with pictures

Comment: "why you use a setInterval for every 1000ms to do what"  -  I don't know :)  It's just and experiment for learning, I thought that it would draw every new image with delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly where you made a misstake. It seems like ALL your images are added at the same time the first time loadImg is called. In order for your example to draw the images with a delay, you need to put a delay on adding the actual sources to your array, so sending only 1 URL per interval.

Since this is an example for you for learning, I won't go into ways how to optimize it.

See the code below, here's a working example of what you want to accomplish. See the comments and hopefully you'll see what's going on.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = 400;
c.height = 400;
var images = [];
var links = ["http://pattersonrivervet.com.au/sites/default/files/pictures/Puppy-10-icon.png",
           "https://38.media.tumblr.com/avatar_2be52b9ba912_128.png"];
var counter = 0;

function draw(imgs){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
    var step = 0;  // I want to start with zero;
    imgs.forEach(function(src){   // then go through the array links
        // and I want to draw the images from the array
        ctx.drawImage(src, 0, step);
        step += src.height;  // This is the step for the next picture. Let's use the height of the image.
    })
}

function loadImg(link){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = link;
    images.push(img);
    draw(images);
};


var myInterval = setInterval(function(){ //I set the interval to a variable so that I can remove it later if needed.
    // you can add images in different ways, I used an array of links
    loadImg(links[counter]);
    
    counter++; //set counter to next image
    if (counter > links.length) {
        //if we're out of images, stop trying to add more
        clearInterval(myInterval); 
    }     
}, 3000);
ctx.fillText("pictures appear in 3s intervals",10,10);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```